# Composite index and locking

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, locking

I'm trying to minimize number of rows locked during a serializable transaction.

The query that seems to be the problem is:

```
UPDATE CLIENTS 
SET SOMEVALUE = 'A' 
WHERE CLIENT_ID = 'aaaa' AND YEAR = 2015
```

Currently there are no indexes, except primary key.

Will creating a composite index (non unique) with `CLIENT_ID` and `YEAR` help with key-range locking?

Comment: What **IS** the primary key??

Comment: primary key is ID int, actually not usable in this particular query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Added an additional resource link after the range keys example.

Adding an index will not necessarily help. Before going that route, I would first capture your actual execution plan for your query and save it.  Next, create statistics for your 2 predicates CLIENT_ID and YEAR.  Run the query again capturing the new query plan and compare the 2.

Below is an example of how to create statistics, view your new statistic, and see the density (uniqueness) and histogram (frequency of key columns) for your statistic.

Having the right statistics really narrows down the number of records returned.

**Example Using AdventureWorks2014:**

```
--Create statistics for the 2 predicates
CREATE STATISTICS PersonType_EmailPromotion ON Person.Person (PersonType, EmailPromotion)

--View your newly created statistic
exec sp_helpstats 'Person.Person', 'ALL'

--See the density and histogram for you statistic
dbcc show_statistics('Person.Person', PersonType_EmailPromotion)
```

**Results dbcc show_statistics**

```
--Notice the uniqueness of PersonType and EmailPromotion compared to PersonType alone.
All density Average Length  Columns
0.1666667   4               PersonType
0.05555556  8               PersonType, EmailPromotion

/*
  This shows the number of rows between PersonType range keys. 
  Notice in, 18329 rows between GC and IN, this is where having 
  2 column statistics really helps narrow down the ranges.
*/
RANGE_HI_KEY    RANGE_ROWS  EQ_ROWS     DISTINCT_RANGE_ROWS AVG_RANGE_ROWS
EM              0           297.2556    0                   1
GC              0           395.5958    0                   1
IN              0           18329.27    0                   1
SC              0           688.3814    0                   1
SP              0           37.99508    0                   1
VC              0           223.5004    0                   1
```

For info on [dbcc show_statistics](http://www.patrickkeisler.com/2013/02/what-is-dbcc-showstatistics-telling-me.html) and [multi-column statistics](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/importance-of-statistics-and-how-it-works-in-sql-server-part-1.html).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

An index will help with key range locking if it ends up being used in the query. Then, it can help reduce the amount of data SQL Server needs to touch and therefore lock.

Add the index and compare actual execution plans before and after. Mostly, you should be doing normal index tuning in this case.